# Angular2 ng2-slider-component bind with model

Tags: angular, slider

I used ng2-slider for price range filter in my application which is developed using angular2 (V2.1.1) . It shows slider as expected . I followed instructions from https://github.com/Bogdan1975/ng2-slider-component . 
Problem is I couldn't found anything which says these are variables to bind with this slider . So I can not access min and max value changed using slider .

Answer (score 0):

min, max, value, startValue, endValue all are default variables of the slider component. You just need to define your relevant variables and assign them to appropriate default variables of the slider component.

```
 <ng2-slider 
        min="myMinVal"
        max="myMaxValue"
        value="myCurrentvalue">

 </ng2-slider>

 export class App{
     myMinVal:number=0;
     myMaxValue:number=100;
     myCurrentValue:number:30;
 }
```

If **number** datatype doesn't work, take **string** type as I'm not aware which datatype will work.

Comment: Thanks @micronyks   for answering . 
I tried your suggestions above . But no one works .myMinVal ,myMaxValue and myCurrentvalue never change once defined .

Answer (score 0):

I just looked into the source code :

you can access all values changed by the slider using `onRangeChange` event

```
<ng2-slider min="3"
    max="33"
    value="7"
    stepValue="1"
    (onRangeChanged)="onRangeChange">
</ng2-slider>


export class MyComponent{

   onRangeChange(data){
      //data.max
      //data.min
      //data.startValue
      //data.endValue
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bougarfaoui for answering .  I read onRangeChange but this function never called on sliding .

Comment: ooh okey the problem is in the module itself

Answer (score 0):

I found answer you can find it over http://bogdan1975.github.io/slider/ .

HTML  :

```
<ng2-slider
        #range
        min="6"
        max="23"
        startValue="9"
        endValue="21"
        (onRangeChanged)="rangeValueChanged($event, 'range-1-start', 'range_1_end')">
</ng2-slider>
<p class="value-box">
    Values: <span class="value-span" id="range-1-start">9</span> - <span class="value-span" id="range-1-end">21</span>
</p>
```

Typescript :

```
rangeValueChanged(event, start:any, end:any) {
    var start_el = this.getElement(start);
    var end_el = this.getElement(end);
    start_el.innerText = event.startValue;
    end_el.innerText = event.endValue;
}

getElement(data){
    if (typeof(data)=='string') {
        return document.getElementById(data);
    }
    if (typeof(data)=='object' && data instanceof Element) {
        return data;
    }
    return null;
}
```